# Inserting and Viewing SQL Table in PHP

Tags: php, sql

config.php is the global file which has the connection codes.

my UPDATED Insert.php code is:

```
<?php

include("config.php");

if ($submit) {
    if (isset($_POST[firstname]) && isset($_POST[lastname]) && isset($_POST[age])) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age) VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";
        mysql_query($sql, $connect); 
        echo "1 record added";
    }
    else {
        // do nothing now
    }
}
else {
?>
<form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF ?>" method="post">
Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname">
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname">
Age: <input type="text" name="age">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
}

//if (!mysql_query($sql,$connect))
 //{
  //die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  //}

mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

my View.php code is:

```
<?php
include("config.php");

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons");
while($results = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo $results['FirstName'] . ', ' . $results['LastName'] . ', ' . $results['Age'] . '<br/>';
}

if (!mysql_query($sql,$connect))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

my Config.php code is:

```
<?php

$dbhost="MYWEBHOST";
$dbusername="MYUSERNAME";
$dbpassword="MYPASSWORD";
$dbname="MYDATABASE";

$connect = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
mysql_select_db($dbname,$connect) or die ("Could not connect to database");

?>
```

After the Insert.php is executed and I receive the "1 Record Added message" and when I go to View.php, I get the following error: "Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Resource id #4' at line 1"

What did I do wrong?

Also How can I prevent user from refreshing the Insert.php page which keeps adding null values to the table?

Comment: added the config.php file codes

Comment: this is weird, are you sure your connection works? Did you try to actually insert anything from `insert.php`? I'm saying this because I see you commented the query execution in this file. It might be that your connection is invalid and when you pass `$connect`, it fails

Comment: in Insert.php, i get the message "1 record added" which mean it's connected successfully or i am to assume otherwise? I should get "no record added" if it wasn't able to connect, right? I commented out CREATE table because it ran once and the table is already created.

Comment: well as you can see, `echo "1 record added";` happens after you setup the string $sql, but you don't actually execute it...

Comment: Sebas i added the following code: "mysql_query($sql, $connect);" before echo "1 record added" which should take care of that. but when I goto view, i get the following: my first name, my last name, my age and then next line, the following error: "Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Resource id #4' at line 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<?php
include("config.php");

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons");
if ($sql) {
    while($results = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo $results['FirstName'] . ', ' . $results['LastName'] . ', ' . $results['Age'] .     '<br/>';
    }
} else {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}


mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

Comment: Now what can i enter in Insert.php to prevent any value added if the user refreshes the page? Should i include the form inside the Insert.php so i can use if($submit){} ?

Comment: This is an arquitectural problem and I think it would be too long to proceed in comments. Basically the idea is to not rely on html forms processed manually anymore, but better doing it through ajax calls.

Comment: I updated the Insert.php. Can you please take a look and should it be sufficient enough to do what I am requesting? Because after I execute and goto View.php, it doesn't show me the new entry in the table.

Comment: I really think you should open a new subject in stack overflow (or read the existing documentation online, which is prolific on the subject)

Comment: i opened a new topic. Thanks for the help on this topic Sebas!

Answer (score 1):

You only assign the SQL statement to a variable, but never execute it. Try this:

`$sql = "INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age) VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";`

`mysql_query($sql);`

`echo "1 record added";`

There are different approachs to prevent people from reloadig your insert.php. In general your insert.php would need to decide wether the user is currently allowed to call it, or not. In modern php development we don't any longer work with single .php files for given tasks, but rather with routes and frameworks.

Comment: Thank you Dirk, I was able to resolve the issue but the view.php is still giving me an issue.
I am new to PHP/SQL scripting, what is routes and frameworks?